# Azure application gateway - caching and routing traffic

Tags: apache, nginx, azure-application-gateway

lets say there are 2 web services. The goal is, that the app gateway routes the requests to both of them. If one of them is down, it should cache all the requests. Once it is up again, which can happen hours later, all the requests cached in the meantime should be send to it in the correct sequence. This is to preserve both services in the same state. Is something like this possible with an application gateway? Or with any other webserver/tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

u can do that but u need some configuration [HTTP Load Balancing](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/)

Load Balancer Overview
The capacity of a single server is limited. Once a website gains more and more attraction the instance serving the site comes to a point where it can not handle any more users. The website starts to slow down or even become unavailable as the server goes down from the traffic.

This is the point where a load balancer enters the game. It allows to spread the “load” that all those visitors and their requests create to be “balanced” over a series of different instances.

In case of increasing load on a setup, capacity can easily be increased by adding more instances to the load balancers backend. This allows to scale your infrastructure without any downtime or delays whilst waiting for DNS zones to be updated.

Comment: I see, but what if one of the backend servers is down for, lets say an hour. The requests arriving during this one hour will not reach that server. And this is a problem, as lets say there was a put request to upload a file for instance during this time frame. This file will not get to that backend server, there will be a difference between the 2 servers.

Comment: u can use the backend for 3 or 10 servers 
http {
   upstream backend {
      server 10.1.0.101; 
      server 10.1.0.102;
      server 10.1.0.103;
   }
and the upload one on S3 or google storage digital ocean storage azure storage it's not big deal at all

Comment: The services are rest APIs of 3rd party tools. In my concrete example I want to keep in sync Nexus artifact repositories. I cannot split the functionalities in any way.